# Почему не обнуляется значение TextBox.Text

Tags: winforms, vb.net, textbox

Есть вот такой код :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Добавил 2 текстовых поля, добавил кнопку соответствующую Button2_Click. Чтобы передать из Текста1 в Тескт2.

Что то понять не могу , почему в TextBox2.Text добавляется дальше текст , который был введен в TextBox1.Text . А точнее после срабатывания клавиши 'Enter'.  А не очищается TextBox2.Text.

Imports не добалял. Может как то это влиять на работу текстового поля ?

Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. В vb net можно сказать новичек , так как большую часть времени в VB6 программил.

Comment: Это Windows Forms/WPF/Web Forms или что-то другое? Укажите соответствующую метку. Также распишите, пожалуйста, по шагам, что именно Вы делаете, что происходит и что ожидалось.

Comment: да это  обычное приложение WindowsForms. Добавил 2 текстовых поля , добавил кнопку соответствующую Button2_Click. Чтобы передать из Текста1 в Тескт2 .. НО не добавлял Imports forms итд.. Может из за этого , такое поведение ТекстБокса .А так ,что не так понять не могу . На VB6 как бы всё просто. А здесь вот такое . Почему здесь TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text , как бы не "обнуляется" TextBox2.Text, а наоборот добавляет после нажатия Enter, если я нажму 2 раз Enter в текстовое поле1.  вот скрин http://prntscr.com/hlzzqd

Comment: На будущее, свои вопросы можно редактировать с помощью кнопки «править» под вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое ощущение, что поле `TextBox1` — многострочное и при нажатии в нем на <kbd>Enter</kbd> происходит перенос на следующую строку. При этом предыдущих строк не видно из-за малого размера поля.

Чтобы проверить это можете увеличить высоту `TextBox1` и посмотреть появляются ли новые строки. Либо выставить в свойство [`ScrollBars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.scrollbars(v=vs.110).aspx) значение `Scrollbars.Vertical` и посмотреть появятся ли полосы прокрутки.

Если `TextBox1` не должно быть многострочным, то проставьте по свойству [`MultiLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx) значение false.

Comment: ну да multiline вкл. , но все ранво же не понятно почему так ? То есть получается в vb net textbox с multiline превращается по типу как массив чтоль ..  Просто в VB6 не так же .. точнее по другому .. И потом вот это TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text , я же как бы полностью присваиваю то переменную точнее текст в полю то .. Вот в этом я не понял ..

Comment: @freefiles в дизайнере `TextBox1` растяните так чтобы несколько строк были видны. После этого запустите программу заново. Думаю, станет понятно.

Comment: @freefiles Если включен `MultiLine`, то поле поддерживает ввод нескольких строк. Тогда `TextBox1.Text` вернет все строки, с [переносами строк](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), объединенные в одно большое значение `string` (что-то вроде `3rer\n8jio...`). В режиме отладки посмотрите значение `TextBox1.Text`

Comment: кстати по поводу этого " в дизайнере TextBox1 растяните так чтобы несколько строк были видны." , ок надо будет посмотреть .. Точно .. наверное так и есть ..тьфу меня .  string (что-то вроде 3rer\n8jio...) - да это я знаю , просто после перехода с VB6 на VS много всего нового , вот и подумал , что не так что то сделал ..  Спасибо , вопрос закрыт !!

Comment: @freefiles Пожалуйста! Рад, что разобрались. Если вопрос закрыт,
 то [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева должна быть серая галка, щелкните на нее).